# escape double quotes inside string literal in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

i need a regex in c# that will escape double quotes inside string literal. so if i have this string: "How about "this" and how about "that"". i will be able to use it in javascript without errors. because i am writing this literal to the page as js var.

**EDIT:** i will try to explain more about the problem.
i writing messege to the page like this:

```
string UserMsg = GetMessageText(999);
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.AppendFormat("var UserMsg =\"{0}\";{1}", UserMsg, Environment.NewLine);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "scriptparams", script.ToString(),true);
```

now lets say messege 999 is this: "we found a "problem" in your details".
this is causing js errors.

Comment: Why do you need a regexp to write javascript to a var using c# to a page .... im confused.com !!!

Comment: So, is your question really "How do I escape a quote character in JS"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not use regular expressions to escape your C# strings into a JavaScript friendly / safe format. Instead, assuming you are using .NET 4, you can use [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx) and it's overload to take care of both single and double quotes for you.

For example:

```
string UserMsg = GetMessageText(999);
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.AppendFormat("var UserMsg =\"{0}\";{1}", HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(UserMsg), Environment.NewLine);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "scriptparams", script.ToString(),true);
```

Would ouput the following with `UserMsg`set to "we found a "problem" in your details":

```
var UserMsg ="we found a \"problem\" in your details";
```

Comment: +1 Now that the question is clearer, this is most definitely the right approach.

Comment: "You should not use regular expressions to escape your C# strings into a JavaScript friendly / safe format." What if your using .net 3.5 and JavaScriptStringEncode is not supported?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I understand you correctly, to escape a `"` in C# source code, you can do it like this:

```
"\""
```

or

```
@""""
```

Either of those literals defines a string containing single double quote character.

---

On the other hand perhaps you need to know how to escape the quote character in Javascript. That is done with `\"`. You can use `String.Replace()` to effect that but you would be much better off with a proper HTML/JS emitter library.

Comment: Aren't you missing a "@" for verbatim strings. Otherwise you'd escape a quote using `\"`, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) (also known as AntiXSS). That has a JavascriptEncode method to do this and other escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
var regex = new Regex("\"");
var result = regex.Replace(stringToReplace, "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this may work:

```
Regex.Replace(myString,'"',"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has been answered already but if you still need the complete code.
below piece of javascript would work for you.
var s = "this is \"Hi \" ";
alert(s);

Praveen